# PAssing PHP variables inside a mysql_query function

Tags: php, mysql

I want to pass a php variable in mysql_query such as:

```
$tty = '217';   

$num_of_comments = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM comments WHERE img_id =  '.$tty.'");
$num_of_comments1 = mysql_fetch_array($num_of_comments);
$num_of_comments2 = $num_of_comments1[0];
echo $num_of_comments2 ;
```

However, I am not able to get the value needed in num_of_comments2. It returns a 0 on echo.

Comment: Use PDO or mysqli and prepared statements: `SELECT count(*) FROM comments WHERE img_id = ?`

Comment: You are entirely misusing the mysql functions. What tutorial are you using to teach you?

Comment: @Jeroien: Could you provide some more insights on using PDO/mysqli function for this problem. How can I write the code for the same?

Comment: You should start with a tutorial or the php manual, there are plenty of examples there.

Answer (score 2):

As the colour coding will show you, your query is wrong. You could also debug it by just `echo`ing your query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM comments WHERE img_id =  '.217.'
```

Clearly incorrect!

```
$tty = '217';   

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM comments WHERE img_id = ".intval($tty));
$row = mysql_fetch_row($sql);
$number = $row[0];
echo $number;
```

Alternative one-liner for getting the value:

```
list($number) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("select count(*) from `comments` where `img_id`=".intval($tty)));
```

Comment: How can I echo the list($number) i.e the count that I get from the sql query?

Comment: This still returns a 0

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$tty = '217';   

$num_of_comments = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM comments WHERE img_id =  '".$tty."'");
$num_of_comments1 = mysql_fetch_array($num_of_comments);
$num_of_comments2 = $num_of_comments1[0];
echo $num_of_comments2 ;
```

Use `'".$tty."'` instead of `'.$tty.'`

Answer (score 0):

Basic PHP syntax:

```
$num_of_comments = mysql_query("[[...snip...]]=  '.$tty.'");
```

You never "closed" your string, so you're trying to execute a PHP concatenation INSIDE your string, which won't work. Your query string is literally going to be

```
WHERE imd_id = '.217.'
                ^---^--- note the concatentation operators
```

For a `"`-quoted string, you do NOT need to concatenate:

```
$num_of_comments = mysql_query([[..snip..] =  '$tty'");
                                              ^^^^^^^---note: no dots
```

is all you need.

Comment: is all you need... if you want a visit from Bobby Tables.

Comment: Tempted to post one of your own `enjoy having your server pwn3d` comments ;-)